# Hide extension in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Hi All
i have a problem that my file have .html extention but i want that when  the file open in brownser the extention had hidden.e.g file.html to file.
Advance thanks

Answer (score 5):

In your `.htaccess` file use this:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Now you can use lins like `http://www.mysite.com/contact` rather than `http://www.mysite.com/contact.html`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks but problem is that they show the contact page in browser but when i write in browser contact.html here extentionshow till refreshing the page.

Comment: I read up to contact.html and you've lost me. What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: make a page contact.html and write the .htaccess and past the above code in .htaccess.now file open in browser they will show you contact but problem is that when you write the .html with contact page in browser then extention is showing but i want extention will no show if i write the .html extention in browser then page no expect this extention .see this link    http://www.myatlantainjurylawyer.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Example **yoursite.com/wallpaper.html to yoursite.com/wallpaper/**

Answer (score 0):

Your link must be like this

```
<a href="example">Example</a>
 Instead of
<a href="example.php">Example</a>
```

Then add this to your .htaccess file

```
 RewriteCond ^example example.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

this one is ok for single extensions in one website. I am using multiple extensions in same website for example index.html and contact.php.

How can i use this code ?