# How to convert book.html to book in htacess

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I have a book.html on my server

I need to access url like that 
http://www.domain.com/book

Is that possible?

Thanks
navi

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729225/hide-extension-in-htaccess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Bhtaccess+%2Bextension

Answer (score 1):

> I have a book.html on my server I need to create a rule some thing like that I 
>   need to access url like that http://www.domain.com/book it will work

That's simple mod_rewrite stuff. If you're using Apache with mod_rewrite enabled:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^book$ /book.html [NC,L]
```

Alternatively, you could use Apache's Multiviews for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

yes write this after `RewriteEngine On`,

```
RewrireRule ^book$ /book.html [NC,L]
```

if you want this rule for all .html files. 
write this

```
RewrireRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ /$1.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^book$ book.html [L]
```

Generally:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
```