# htaccess How to add filenextention

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have seen may pages witch are to call just by

www.page.com/name

To get this, I thing, I have to change the .htaccess
But I do not have any clue how?

Calling this: www.page.com/name shout give www.page.com/name.html
(name shout be a variable name)

Do I get any help here?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: i hope this help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729225/hide-extension-in-htaccess

Comment: I looked at it before. But I thought that is only hiding the extension.
My wish is to add a extension.
But it seems to work in both directions.
I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.html to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

## To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```